# Forward JSON payload sent to 1 URL out to 3 other URLs?

Tags: .net, iis

We have VOIP phones with the ability to send event data to a webhook url on our API. The issue is we can only use 1 URL on the phone and need that payload to end up on 3 different URLs. Essentially we are trying to get all our event data sent from the phone to go to our 3 pipeline stages in development. Can this be done?

So far we have tried IIS rewrites / redirects but you can only send out to 1 url not all 3 at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest writing a generic handler that consumes the payload and then using System.Net.HttpWebRequest to send it to the other three.